# jQuery Submit Form (w/ file and text) without redirecting from current window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to build an application *form* where on can attach an image - it's just a couple of input elements - within a `div` (not an form element). The form shall be processed without an page redirect. So I use ajax. Everything works fine so far. But now I need to add an image.

```
$('#submit_application').click(function () {
//...
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'action': 'submit',
            'image': $('#image_upload').val(),
             // ..
            'someStringifiedJSON': JSON.stringify(foo)
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
            // ...
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get my file into php's `$_FILES` variable? Or how can I pass the file to php so that I can upload it?

Comment: It's good practice to use a form, and prevent it's submit with javascript e.preventDfault() method, so it can be used also if js is disabled.

Comment: If none of the answer here are what you need, take a look at [this](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @EternalHour I provided a working answer already.  If you have nothing better to do, maybe post your own working code.  Though I don't see the point as this question has already been answered correctly.

Comment: @brettetete I post a working answer.  I tested it and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send files using [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects).

```
var file = $('#image_upload')[0].files[0];
var fData = new FormData();
fData.append('action', 'submit');
fData.append('image', file);
fData.append('someStringifiedJSON', JSON.stringify(foo));
```

and your ajax request will be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: fData ,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data, status) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

as specefied [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).if you set `processData` to true it will pass it as query string.if you want to send non-processed data set it to `false`.

default for contentType is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.which won't work for files (because it sends heder like `multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------125911542220235`) when you set it to false browser generate right content-type header automatically

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in jquery.2.1.3.min.js

Comment: sorry you have to put ('contentType': false 'processData': false) to settings object.edited

Comment: Yeah that solves the problem. Perfect. I'll mark this as the correct answer. But could you please add some info about `contentType: false` and `processData: false`

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Probably because there is no answer of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#submit_application').click(function () {
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('action','submit');
    formData.append('someStringifiedJSON', ''+JSON.stringify(foo));
    formData.append($('#image_upload').files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type: 'post',
        contentType:false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data, status) {
            // ...
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to add this `contentType:false` in ajax request.

Comment: didn't you just copy the other guys answer who posted this 5 mins ago?

Comment: same problem as with Omars answer.

Comment: @notorious pet0 can't you see the difference?